# Configuring a biblatex bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I just switched from natbib to biber + biblatex, and the closest bibliography style to my preferred style is "ieee" (by Joseph Wright).  I am using it with the citation style "authoryear".  This makes the numbers in the bibliography useless; how do I remove them?

Comment: Did you consider the `ieee-alphabetic` style?

Comment: @JosephWright: I just tried that, but it adds [AuthYear] marks in the bibliography.  Since I'm using the citation style author-year, I probably don't need those.  Essentially, I want "ieeetrann" from natbib.  Is there an easy way to get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but it should be possible to load `biblatex` with the options `citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=ieee` and then to add `authoryear`'s bibenvironment definition to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  It worked.