# Print year after author in biblatex' numeric style

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the default style `numeric` in `biblatex`. In this style, the year is printed last in the bibliography:
[image]

I would like to have the year directly after the author's name:

> George Harrison. 2000. *My music is better than Paul's and John's*.

What command can I put into the preamble of my `.tex` file to enforce this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,biblatex,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{harrison2000,
    AUTHOR = "George Harrison",
    TITLE = "My music is better than Paul's and John's",
    YEAR = "2000"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Text \parencite{harrison2000}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need to change every `BibliographyDriver` -- the solution is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61373/510): load `biblatex` with the options `citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear` and add the `\defbibenvironment` definion of `numeric.bbx`. (The [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package is only used to remove the parentheses around the year.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes,filecontents}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{harrison2000,
    AUTHOR = "George Harrison",
    TITLE = "My music is better than Paul's and John's",
    YEAR = "2000"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Text \parencite{harrison2000}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Now I also learned how to remove parentheses from the year in the bibliography. I tested this, and it works with other styles too, such as `style=authoryear`.

Comment: @Sverre See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style

Answer (score 3):

For somethings you can just set an option/toggle to change the formatting. There is a nice explanation in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles). Moving the date is not that simple. There currently is not a [WYSIWYG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67248/is-there-a-wysiwyg-editor-for-biblatex-styles) editor for `biblatex` styles or even a system like [makebst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) so your best bet is to find an existing style that meets your needs (or change your needs). If you really want to do it, you could redefine a bunch of macros in the preamble, but it will be much easier to create your own style.

Starting from `standard.bbx` you would need to redefine all the `bibmacros` which have "date" in their name like

```
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

to be

```
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit}
```

and then replace the references to the date version with the no date version. This will get rid of the date at the end of the reference.

Adding the date to the beginning of the reference requires adding

```
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
```

to each `BibliographyDriver` in the appropriate place. For example, for books

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
```

would become

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
```

Comment: Wow, that entails a _lot_ more stuff in the preamble than I had hoped for! Furthermore, I realized there is more stuff to sort out. For instance, some `bibmacros` have more than one `\usebibmacro{date}` fields. Then what? Delete all? Also, many of the `BibliographyDriver`s make reference to fields such as `\usebibmacro{location+date}`. But these don't exist anymore, since I've removed the `date` part.

Comment: @Sverre I said it wasn't trivial. I definitely would define a new style (or better yet find a existing style that meets your requirements). As for the `+date` part, yes you need to modify everything.