# Biblatex: change order of year, year without brackets in numeric-style

Tags: biblatex

I was wondering if some one knows how I can move the year (and without any brackets) right after the journal name?

I should look like this:

> [1] R. Chevalier, B. Colsch, C. Afonso, N. Baumann, J.-C. Tabet, J.-M. Mallet, Tetrahedron Letter **2006**, 62, 563.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ 
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric 
]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{% 
bibencoding=utf8, 
bibwarn=true, 
sortlocale=de_DE, 
isbn=false, 
url=false, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
clearlang=true, 
maxbibnames=99, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=none, 
} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\bfseries{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage[{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]}]{#1}} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
   page = {{}{}}, 
   pages = {{}{}}, 
} 
\bibliography{Lit/OCPrakt} 


\begin{document} 
blablabla\cite{Bromierung} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

.bib-file:

```
@article{Bromierung, 
   Author = {Reynald Chevalier and Beno{\^\i}t Colsch and Carlos Afonso and Nicole Baumann and Jean-Claude Tabet and Jean-Maurice Mallet}, 
   Date-Added = {2013-10-28 10:46:57 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2013-11-11 20:26:08 +0000}, 
   Journal = {Tetrahedron Letter}, 
   Pages = {563-577}, 
   Read = {0}, 
   Title = {Synthetic sulfated glucuronosyl paragloboside (SGPG) and its use for the detection of autoimmune peripheral neuropathies}, 
   Volume = {62}, 
   Year = {2006}}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95337/15925 help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried but didn't work for me. I guess that I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: You say you want the year after the authors, but your example has it after the title.  Which format do you really want?

Comment: sorry, I mean the year after the journal..

Answer (score 5):

You need to renew the macros for `journal+issuetitle` and `issue+date`, the first to fix the ordering, the second to remove the parentheses:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ 
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric
]{biblatex} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{% 
bibencoding=utf8, 
bibwarn=true, 
sortlocale=de_DE, 
isbn=false, 
url=false, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
clearlang=true, 
maxbibnames=99, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=none, 
} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\bfseries{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage[{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]}]{#1}} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
   page = {{}{}}, 
   pages = {{}{}}, 
} 

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}% 
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}


\addbibresource{OCPrakt.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Text~\cite{Bromierung}.

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```