# Print year after author in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to get my bibliography sorted. So far I have managed to get it looking like this:

[image]

Note:The page number for reference one is messed up in this minimal example, but it works fine on my original document for some reason.

What I would like to modify:

1) Year field 
a) positioned after authors
b) without brackets
c) followed by a full stop

I tried [Print year after author in biblatex' numeric style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95337/print-year-after-author-in-biblatex-numeric-style) but it didn't work for me.

2) Title field
a) followed by a stop than a comma

3) For some reason the second reference (for which I have supplied the location) prints the date differently. I want to avoid this.

If you spot any redundancies in my code or if there is an easier way to do some of things I have tried to do, please let me know.

Minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% To use \includegraphics
% To produce graphs from data files
% To generate tables from .csv
% To list acronyms
% To modify page margins
% To allow booktabs
% To allow rotated text
% To allow multirow text in tables
% To create a longtable
% To use SI units
% To create logos on every page
% Used in conjunction with gensymb
% To allow use of degree symbol
% To include a pdf page
% To allow numberwithin to be used
% To allow subfigures
% To show multiple columns in a page
% To make subliminal refinements
% To get last page number
% To start page numbering only at a certain page
% To print inline fractions
% To insert page in landscape
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfplots,pgfplotstable, acronym, fullpage, booktabs, rotating, multirow, longtable, siunitx, fancyhdr, textcomp, gensymb, pdfpages, amsmath, subcaption, multicol, microtype, lastpage, afterpage, xfrac, pdflscape}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=centerlast]{caption}                                      % To use captions
\usepackage{floatrow}                   % Captions same size as figure
\usepackage[titletoc, page]{appendix}   % To number appendix in toc
\usepackage[section]{placeins}          % To stop figures floating across sections
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        % For clickable urls
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}         % To allow \cref to be used
\crefname{appsec}{Appendix}{Appendices} % Appendix references labelled correctly
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % Use EC fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Encoding
\usepackage{csquotes}                   % To manage quotes
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Language selection
\usepackage{listings}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% REFERENCING PACKAGE
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,isbn=false,doi=true,url=true,firstinits=true, maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
% To allow modifications of bibliography
\usepackage{xpatch}
% To write bibtex file
\usepackage{filecontents}
% To make doi links
\usepackage{doi}                

% Change bibliography numbering style to 1. rather than [1]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}

% Comma as separator in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} 

% Order bibliography by last name
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

% Insert thin spaces between author initials
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}

% `Year` field after author names
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
\printfield{prefixnumber}%
\printfield{labelnumber}}}
{\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

% Full stop after `year` field
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
\printtext[parens]%
}{%
\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printtext%
}{}{}

% No quotes for `title` field
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot} 

% Get rid of 'In:' in reference list
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

% No prefix for the `pages` field
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} 

% Make `volume` field in bold
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}} 

% Place volume number within parentheses:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}
\printfield{volume}
\setunit*{\addnbthinspace} %there's also \addnbspace
\printfield{number}
\setunit{\addcomma\space}
\printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{cooperman2013,
title       = {{Active Load Control of a Wind Turbine Airfoil Using Microtabs}},
author  = {Cooperman, A M and Chow, Raymond and van Dam, C P},
journal     = {Journal of Aircraft},
month       = 8,
year        = 2013,
volume      = 50,
number  = 4,
pages       = {1150–-1158},
doi         = {10.2514/1.C032083},
}
@conference{flowvisualisation,
author       = {Powell, K L and Parker, K and Soria, J}, 
title        = {Flow visualisation of forced flow control over inclined aerofoils},
year         = 2004,
address      = {Sydney, Australia},
month        = 12,
organization = {The University of Sydney},
url            = {http://www.aeromech.usyd.edu.au/15afmc/proceedings/papers/AFMC00207.pdf},
note       = {15th Australasian Fluid Mechanics Conference},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\Textcite{cooperman2013}
\Textcite{flowvisualisation}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `style=authoryear, labelnumber` instead of `citestyle=authoryear` the method from your link works perfectly and issue 3 disappears immediately. Other than that your MWE is far to massive to properly work with.