# biblatex-biber: How to customize the order in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber

I am having difficulties with setting up the layout of my bibliography.
I would like to have a numeric style which does a none sorting so its order is as it appears in the text. Plus I would like my bibliography entry to look like this (so authoryear style):

> #### References
>
> [1] Surname, Y.G. Year. Title ...

I don't know what to do and can't come up with anymore keywords to look for it. I just started using `biblatex`.

My setup is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=numeric-comp
    sorting=none,
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}

Structures \cite{definition}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code blocks by either indenting them by four spaces or by selecting them and hitting `{}` from the editing gui.

Comment: Please give more information what exactly your problem is.

Comment: A numeric style (getting little numbers pointing to the numbered bibliography entries) contradicts with an authoryear style (putting the names and years in the text and the bibliography).

Comment: I don´t want the authoryear style for the text. I´d like the numeric style but have my bibliography look like authoryear. There must be a way ?!

Comment: Sure there's a way (not necessarily easy), but I hope you realize that "authoryear" is not a style per se, but a general description of how bibliographical information should be sorted.  An actual "authoryear" **style** usually involves a very detailed specification.  Saying you want to use "authoryear" is kind of like saying you want a "primate" when you actually mean you want a squirrel monkey.

Comment: What you have shown in the question is a numeric bibliography style, you have a numeric label. To change the order of elements, you would have to change every single bibliographydriver and swap orders.

Comment: Do you have a link to some instructions or explanations how to change the bibliographydrivers ?

Comment: See also [Print year after author in biblatex' numeric style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95337/35864)

Comment: See also [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24501/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `biblatex`'s `numeric` styles use a `authortite`-flavoured bibliography style. But with a little trick we can make it use a `authoryear` one.

For this, use `citestyle=numeric-comp, bibstyle=authoryear,` as optional argument to `biblatex` and add

```
\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. Then the `numeric` bibstyle is applied to `authoryear`.
This works because the numeric bibliography style `numeric.bbx` acts as a sort of "add-on" to the `standard.bbx` style and changes only definitions that do not conflict with `authoryear.bbx`.

It then only remains to drop the parentheses. The approach here was taken from [lockstep's answer to biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12254/35864).
It requires the [`xpatch`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package

```
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilde,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For sorting you probably just want `sorting=none,`.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! It works without a problem, very helpful !!!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for, is the style of the bibliography. Maybe
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles
will help you

Comment: That won't do any good, the styles (bst) of the BibTeX system are unrelated and incompatible with `biblatex` styles.