# How to enumerate latex used bibliography list?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm having problems enumerating my bibliography list. I'm using these lines to define my bibliography style:

```
\usepackage[sort,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

I know I could use:

```
\usepackage[sort,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

And it would result in numbered citations list, like:

```
[1] Author. 2015. Paper.
[2] Second Author. 2011. Paper.
...
```

But the problem is that references change (`\citep` and `\cite`). In text instead of reference (Author, 2015) it becomes numbers like [1]. I want to keep my `apalike` style references, and add numbers to each item in my bibliography list. How do I do that? I tried adding `\begin{enumerare}` and `\item` near each `\bibitem`  and `\end{enumerare}`. It didn't work.

Comment: The question you raise -- how to get explicit enumeration of the items in the bibliography even though you're using author-year citation call-outs -- comes up regularly on this site. The general answer may not be what you'd like to be told: What's the point of having such an enumeration scheme? It would seem to serve no useful purpose, but it woukd add typographic clutter.

Comment: Requirement from higher authority for paper, no more. I totally agree, that numbering is silly, but might be because they [authority] want to know how many citations there actually are, but they can't just say count them and write it down.

Comment: You have tagged your question `biblatex`, if you would like to use `biblatex`, [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24501/35864) or [biblatex-biber: How to customize the order in the bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248726/35864) (you will need `citestyle=authoryear, labelnumber,` with the latter) might be of help. (Your case is even easier: Just load a `authoryear` style and add `\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother`) If not you might want to change the tags so as to not confuse people.

Comment: The above solution of adding `\makeatletter \input{numeric.bbx} \makeatother` works even with `biblatex-apa`.