# Combining style numeric with style authoryear in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I haven't had a lot of experience with `biblatex` so far and I decided to use the numeric style for citations in the text. However, the authoryear style for the bibliography is much nicer. I know, I can't actually combine `numeric` citestyle with `authoryear` bibstyle.

That brings me to my question: How can I achieve using the numeric citestyle and the formatting of authoryear in the bibliography?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go down the route from [biblatex-biber: How to customize the order in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248726/35864).

Call `citestyle=numeric` (or the member of the `numeric` family you currently use) and `bibstyle=authoryear`, then import `numeric.bbx` to get the proper `bibliography` environment again.

(The sorting will by default be `sorting=nyt`, if you want `sorting=none` you will need to order that explicitly.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %sorting=none,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilde,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: That works great, could you additionally tell me how to achieve that the last name comes first (I'm using firstinits=true)?

Comment: @OliverBorchert Are you looking for `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}` (or `last-first` in pre-3.3 `biblatex`)?

Comment: I actually don't know what that means, the first one basically works, however the authors are not depicted accurately (always one or two, no et al., although maxbibnames=2) and there is no space between last and first name and between the authors

Comment: Ok, I figured it out .. (last-first instead of family-given) .. as I said .. not a lot of experience ..

Comment: Is it possible to have one bibliography in the `numeric` style and another in the `authoryear` style? I've added a bibliography for uncited references, and the numbers don't make much sense there.

Comment: @TakingItCasual In general it is not easy to combine different citation styles in the same document, but in your use case that seems possible. Add something like `\defbibenvironment{aybibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}` to the preamble and print the bibliography with the uncited entries with `\printbibliography[env=aybibliography, omitnumbers]`. That needs the `defernumbers` option.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much for this simple solution. This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
 \AtEveryBibitem{[\printfield{labelnumber}]\addspace}%Numbers in the bib
 \begin{document}

 \cite{herrmann}, \cite{doody}, 

 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! However, I have one more question: the numeric bibstyle kind of has an alignment character so that when the number exceeds 9 (10 etc.), the authors are still aligned correctly and not slightly shifted to the right. How can I achieve that?