# How to put square brackets around a number in biblatex authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, numbering

I use the authoryear style in biblatex and want to create a number before the entries just like in the numeric style. I managed to get the numbers but would also like to have square brackets around them an get rid of the dot after the number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false,backend=biber,eprint=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate
    {}
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{DiGiuseppe2016,
    Title                    = {{Borrowed Time: Sovereign Finance, Regime Type, and Leader Survival}},
    Author                   = {DiGiuseppe, Matthew and Shea, Patrick E.},
    Journal                  = {Economics and Politics},
    Year                     = {2016},
    Number                   = {3},
    Pages                    = {342--367},
    Volume                   = {28},
    Doi                      = {10.1111/ecpo.12081},
    ISBN                     = {1468-0343},
    ISSN                     = {14680343}
}

@Article{Dixit2000,
    Title                    = {{Political Power and the Credibility of Government Debt}},
    Author                   = {Dixit, Avinash and Londregan, John},
    Journal                  = {Journal of Economic Theory},
    Year                     = {2000},
    Number                   = {1},
    Pages                    = {80--105},
    Volume                   = {94},

    Doi                      = {10.1006/jeth.2000.2684},
    ISSN                     = {00220531}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Text \cite{Dixit2000} More Text \cite{DiGiuseppe2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the default. Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Bernard the numbers in the bibliography are not shown for author-year citations by default, the OP apparently wants to combine the two styles.

Comment: If you have numbers in the bibliography they are going to be much more prominent than the author and the year - almost obscuring them. For a reader it will be harder to look past the numbers to find the correct author-year combination that matches the citation label. I don't think it is a good idea to mix `authoryear` and `numeric` like this. I'd find something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864 less confusing if you insist on numbers in the bibliography. If you don't strictly need them, `style=authoryear` as it is by default might be the better choice.

Comment: The problem of the mentioned solution is that I need the authoryear citation style in the text and I need the numbers in the bibliography.

Comment: Indeed. But I was trying to persuade you that what you want is not ideal. The bibliography will be quite a bit harder to navigate for your reader.

Comment: You can (and might) convince me. But not my professor ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the package `enumitem` you can customize the `enumerate` environment. Modify your MWE with the following code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate[label={[\arabic*]}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This anwer is not usable without the context. Is there a more general solution?

Comment: @JHBonarius the approach of the question is applicable in general (i.e., combine an `authoryear` style in the main text with an `enumerate` style in the reference list), as is my solution to the specific problem (i.e., change the appearance of the `enumerate` labels). In a different context, well, you should change the context accordingly - but the approach of the solution remains the same. As it is currently presented in the question it is already a rather general case (except maybe for some unnecessary `biblatex` options), how would you propose to make it more general?

Comment: Well, for my case (using `style=science`) the solution turned out to be to use `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}`. However, I've posted an answer with my proposed solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was available in januari 2016, bu nowadays you can have a seperate `bibstyle` and `citestyle`. E.g.:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric,backend=biber,eprint=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You'll notice subtle differences between the outcome of this solution and the other answer. In particular Marijn's answer retains the order of "Author (Year). Title" in the bibliography, while `bibstyle=numeric` moves the year to the back of the entry. This may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Good point. Well, I'll just keep this answer here for reference.