# Numbered In-text Citations With APA Style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I am trying to create a bibliography that uses the APA style, but with numbered in-text citations (e.g. [#] ). At present, my in-text citations are in the more traditional form of (author, year).
I have included a MWE of this below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}  
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Example \cite{kearon1998noninvasive}.
\interlinepenalty=10000
\bibliography{References.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The example References.bib is given by

```
@article{kearon1998noninvasive,
  title={Noninvasive diagnosis of deep venous thrombosis},
  author={Kearon, Clive and Julian, Jim A and Math, M and Newman, Toni E and Ginsberg, Jeffrey S},
  journal={Annals of internal medicine},
  volume={128},
  number={8},
  pages={663--677},
  year={1998},
  publisher={American College of Physicians}
}
```

[image]

I have read through the apacite package manual and am unsure of how this can be achieved. Is it even possible?

Comment: The APA6 formatting guidelines, which are implemented in the `apacite` package and `apacite` bibliography style, allow authoryear-style citation call-outs only.

Comment: @Mico Is there any way around this (perhaps using a different package)?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of bibliography styles that (a) implement the APA's guidelines for formatted bibliographies yet also (b) generate numeric-style citation call-outs. Maybe somebody else is familiar with such styles, though.

Comment: @Mico I hope so! Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Do I understand you correct, if I say you want the references in the bibliography printed in the order given by apacite but with an index you can use to cite?

If thats true, you might get off with using biblatex' numeric style and changing the order of the items as described here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles

Comment: @MichaelBölting Thanks for your response. You are basically correct. I want the references in the bibliography to be in the format of apacite (e.g. Author/s. (Year). Title. Journal, etc.) but with a numerical index (e.g. [1], [2], etc). When using `\cite`, it should display [1] and not the conventional APA format of (Author, Year).

Comment: I see you do NOT use `biblatex`. Want to keep it that way, `bibtex` only?

Comment: @jarnosz Please include `biblatex`

Comment: Not quite following: citation should be somewhat like `[1] Kearon, C. et al. (1998). Noninvasive diagnosis... 128 (8): 633-677.` AND a solution in EITHER pure bibtex OR biblatex. Correct?

Comment: I am not sure about how to handle an answer to this question: typically answers are expected to be self contained, but I found that a full bibliography style, which in my opinion is the right approach. is too large to fit into an answer. May I just point to a public repository with the relevant files and outline the answer in this site? I already tried to do something in this direction, but I am not sure if it is acceptable.

Comment: @jarnosz Yes, if you're willing to make the link semi-permanent, like in a gihub repo, that would be fine. I have an "unsuported" repo that contains such things that I've accumulated over the years.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want the output to be. Can you choose from the following options: A: numeric in text in order of citation, with numbered bibliography but formatted as 1. Author (year) ... , etc. B: numeric in text based on alphabetic sorting of the bibliography, with numbered bibliography 1. Author (year) ... etc.?

Comment: As you may see, I believe you do not need `biblatex` at all; at least for this particular job.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy to do with `biblatex`. I would not use the actual `apa` style, however, since it is not designed to be used like this. Instead use the more generic `author-year` style. Here I've used the `ext-authoryear` style which allows for some simple adjustments from the default `author-year` style. This implements option B in my comment on your question, where the numbering reflects the alphabetical order of the references not the citation order, which I think is the most sensible combination for this sort of bibliography.

### Robust solution

As moewe notes in the comments, my original quick and dirty solution really fakes the numbering of the bibliography lines with respect to the references in the text, since there is no actual connection to them. Although this will work for many cases, it's not fully robust, so the proper way to do this is to use the actual formatting provided from the `numeric.bbx` code in `biblatex`.  So this is the proper way to do things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=ext-authoryear,articlein=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{yoon,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Quick and dirty solution

For a quick and dirty solution which will work for many cases, you can  use the technique outlined in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410643/2693) for the numbering of the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=ext-authoryear,articlein=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate[label={[\arabic*]}]}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\begin{document}
\cite{yoon,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Note that if you use `enumerate` for the numbering in the bibliography there is no real connection between the number you see in citations and the bibliography. The numbers will usually line up, but that is just 'accidental'. Things may go wrong in a split bibliography without `defernumbers` and things will also go wrong if there is an entry with `shorthand`. I'd copy the [`\defbibenvironment` from `numeric.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/3f9f6dfc6ae363d2d39cbde0045a32c1658f7d99/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx#L24-L37).

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I've updated the answer with that solution.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the days of yore (I mean: before biblatex) you had to concoct your own `bst` (bibliography style) file in pure BAFLL (BibTeX's Anonymous Forth Like Language) to process your bibliography with BibTeX, which was a pain, because... well, it was a FLL.

Fortunately, there is a nice little package called [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) which includes a nice little TeX program `makebst` to produce TeX batch files (`dbj`) to generate custom `bst` files trying to fulfill your expectations.

So, basically, you run

```
tex makebst
```

in your terminal, and the program leads you through an interactive interface, where you may select the options required to produce your style. At the end of the process, the program generates a `dbj` file, which is yet another TeX file you may run to produce the final `bst` file with your bibliographic style. This way, if you change your mind (of find out you fouled up), you may edit the `dbj` file, comment in/out the options of your choice, and produce yet another `bst` by running

```
tex yourstyle.dbj
```

You may still hack/kludge the final `bst` file a bit; but again, programming in pure BAFLL may be EXTREMELY PAINFUL if you are not used to it. `makebst` does a nice little job to jumpstart your task, and tweaking the byproducts is **relatively** easy.

Given the system's limits for answers, and following Alan Munn's advice in the comments, I am posting here a link to a first attempt to suit your needs: the batch file and generated bibliography style are posted on GitHub.

https://gist.github.com/jarnosz/931d6eb5ae1eef2c58407f8d3f9ec5ff

The bibliography style tries to implement what you ask for.

```
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------
 % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
 % This is a numerical citation style, and as such is standard LaTeX.
 % It requires no extra package to interface to the main text.
 % The form of the \bibitem entries is
 %   \bibitem{key}...
 % Usage of \cite is as follows:
 %   \cite{key} ==>>          [#]
 %   \cite[chap. 2]{key} ==>> [#, chap. 2]
 % where # is a number determined by the ordering in the reference list.
 % The order in the reference list is alphabetical by authors.
 %---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just remember to declare your `\bibliographystyle{plainad}`: as the comment says, neither `apacite.sty` nor any other macro interface is required; so this bibstyle may work even in Plain TeX.

Here are the results:

[image: citation]

[image: bibentry]