# printing bibliography with numbers in order of year or in order of citation with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

For a CV I want my bib-items to be sorted with respect to the year with the most recent item appearing first. In addition I have to use a certain style sheet, the Unified Style Sheet for Linguistics. The sorting option seems to do what I want but it does not do so when combined with the style. The order of output should be:

```
[1] Müller, 2018
[2] Müller & Ørsnes, 2015
[3] Müller, 2013
```

Is it possible to generate numbered output, e.g. as above with `[1], [2], [3]`?

The style files are here: https://github.com/langsci/latex/tree/master/langsci/bst

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\usepackage[
natbib=true,
style=biblatex-sp-unified,
    %citestyle=numeric,
    citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp,
    sorting=ydnt,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}

@book{MOeDanish,
Address = {Berlin},
Author = {Stefan Müller and Bjarne Ørsnes},
Publisher = {Language Science Press},
Series = {Empirically Oriented Theoretical Morphology and Syntax},
Title = {{Danish in Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar}},
Year = {2015}}

@book{MuellerHPSG3,
Address = {Tübingen},
Author = {Stefan Müller},
Edition = {3},
Number = {17},
Publisher = {Stauffenburg Verlag},
Series = {Stauffenburg Einführungen},
Title = {{Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar: Eine Einführung}},
Year = {2013}}

@book{MuellerLFGphrasal,
Address = {Berlin},
Author = {Stefan Müller},
Booktitle = {Phrasal Constructions, Derivational Morphology, Constituent Structure and (Cross-Linguistic) Generalizations: {A} Discussion of Template-Based Phrasal {LFG} Approaches},
Publisher = {Language Science Press},
Series = {Conceptual Foundations of Language Science},
Title = {Phrasal Constructions, Derivational Morphology, Constituent Structure and (Cross-Linguistic) Generalizations: {A} Discussion of Template-Based Phrasal {LFG} Approaches},
Year = {2018}}



\end{filecontents}


\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}


\begin{refsection}

\nocite{MOeDanish,MuellerHPSG3,MuellerLFGphrasal}

\printbibliography[heading=none,notkeyword=this]

\end{refsection}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Which tex distribution do you use? TeX Live, MiKTeX, ...?

Comment: Can't you just do `style=biblatex-sp-unified, citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp,`? If these files indeed live in `/Users/stefan/Library/texmf/tex/latex/langsci/bst/` or subdirectories they should be found. (Of course you need to `texhash` after install). If you run `kpsewhich biblatex-sp-unified.bbx` from the command line what response do you get?

Comment: The sorting works as expected for me in your MWE. You can number your items with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864

Comment: Sorry for the path question. It does work. I had an earlier situation where I had problems. I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the numbering! Everything works now. Maybe the question should be deleted ...

Comment: Either that or we mark it as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864

Comment: So, what do we do? If you don't mind, I'll vote to close as a duplicate - the "golden hammer" means that there will be no voting about it, though, so if you disagree, give me a shout.