# customize in-text citation call-outs

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am using `biber` for my bibliography. I try to edit my in-text bibliography style to appear like this:

> Blah blah[1] blah blah blah [1-3].

What I am try to change is like:

> Blah blah (Koehler 1999) blah blah blah (Koehler 1999, Bailey et al.,Lam 2016).

This is simple of my latex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sqcases}{%
\matrix@check\sqcases\env@sqcases
}{%
\endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@sqcases{%
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\left\lbrack
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, citetracker=true, maxcitenames=1, giveninits, terseinits, uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{2}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{koehler1999digital,
    title={Digital libraries and World Wide Web sites and page persistence},
    author={Koehler, Wallace},
    journal={Information research},
    volume={4},
    number={4},
    pages={4--4},
    year={1999}
}

@article{bailey2016exponent,
    title={Exponent of Cross-Sectional Dependence: Estimation and Inference},
    author={Bailey, Natalia and Kapetanios, George and Pesaran, M Hashem},
    journal={Journal of Applied Econometrics},
    volume={31},
    number={6},
    pages={929--960},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library},
    doi = {10.1002/jae.2476}
}
@article{lam2016nonparametric,
    title={Nonparametric eigenvalue-regularized precision or covariance matrix estimator},
    author={Lam, Clifford},
    journal={The Annals of Statistics},
    volume={44},
    number={3},
    pages={928--953},
    year={2016},
    publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
    doi = {0.1214/15-AOS1393}
}
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\printlist{location}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon {\addcomma\space}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
\maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
        \pertype{article}
        \step[fieldset=number, null]
    }
}
}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}


\begin{document}

Blah blah \parencite{koehler1999digital} blah blah blah 
\parencite{koehler1999digital}, \parencite{bailey2016exponent} 
\parencite{lam2016nonparametric}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I try to change `\parencite{koehler1999digital}` to  `\parencite{koehler1999digital}` but it does not work.

Any idea about what I am missing here ?

Comment: `style=numeric-comp` instead of `style=authoryear-comp`?

Comment: @moewe it changes it but the  bibliography list in the end on article is gone !

Comment: Your renewcommand for \bibpagespunct is missing a } at the end.  I can get what you are after using @moewe suggestion for style change, but also changing your cite line to: \parencite{koehler1999digital,bailey2016exponent,lam2016nonparametric}

Comment: The `\bibpagespunct` should be `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma\space}}`. And you will indeed have to write `\parencite{koehler1999digital,bailey2016exponent,lam2016nonparametric}` for the citations to come out as "[1-3]". Delete your temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile. If that does not work we would need to know if there are any errors or warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` file.

Comment: @moewe ok the bibliography is come back but the style of  the bibliography is changed too. I just want to change in-text references to numeric with keeping my  the bibliography style as it was without editing: `Bailey N, Kapetanios G, Pesaran M H (2016) Exponent of cross-sectional dependence: estimation and inference. Journal of Applied Econometrics 31: 929-960. https://doi.org/10.1002/jae.2476`

Comment: On second thoughts, `citestyle=numeric-comp, bibstyle=authoryear` alone is not a great idea. You may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864

Comment: Thanks for your advice but the journal asking me to do this. Thanks for your help its works fine now.

Comment: The numbers in-text is not in ascending order, its starts from 4 and 21 etc. Is there way to re-arrange them?

Comment: Does that mean the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864 answers your question? If you want to sort the citations by order of appearance, add `sorting=none` to the `biblatex` options. (BTW: If you are submitting to a journal, check out if they accept `biblatex` submissions and read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)

Comment: `sorting=none` solved the problem. I've checked my journal there is no problem with submission `biblatex`. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Good. I'd like to close this question as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314014/35864, since that is what solved the issue at the heart of your question. Would that be OK with you?

Comment: No problem with that  :)