# Citations appearing as numeric values

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I am having problems setting up my bibliography. I am using Harvard citation style yet my citations are appearing as numbers as shown in the picture below:
[image: Problem description]
If I remove the options `super,comma,numbers` of the `natbib` package, I get the desired output **though this will result in the disappearance of the numbering labels of my references in the Bibliography** which is something I do not like. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[ 
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm, 
top=3cm,
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3\baselineskip,
headsep = 5mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\setlength\bibindent{0pt}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=yellow,
}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    I want this citation \cite{hapa:graphenum} to be \textcolor{red}{Harary and Palmer }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1973})}. I want this citation \cite{Knuth94:TheTeXbook} to be \textcolor{red}{Knuth }\textcolor{black}{(\textcolor{red}{1994})}.This text is quoted from \cite{datta2017latex} should be (\textcolor{red}{Datta\textcolor{black}{,} 2017}).
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \backmatter
    
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{references}
    
\end{document}
```

Below is the references.bib:

```
@book{hapa:graphenum,
    author =     {F. Harary and E. M. Palmer},
    title =      {Graphical Enumeration},
    publisher =      {Academic Press},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1973
}
@book{Knuth94:TheTeXbook,
    author =     {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
    title =      {The \TeX book},
    publisher =      {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
    pages={465--523},
    year =   1994,
    series =     {Computers \& Typesetting A},
    address =    {Reading, MA},
    titlenote  =        {with illustrations by Duane Bibby}
}
@book{datta2017latex,
    title={LaTeX in 24 Hours: A Practical Guide for Scientific Writing},
    author={Datta, Dilip},
    pages={465--523},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at `biblatex`  functionalities.

Comment: You're loading `natbib` this way: `\usepackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}`. Not surprisingly you're getting superscripted numeric citations. Remove those options and see what you get. If you need conforming APA style, you should use either the `apacite` package or `biblatex` with the `apa` style. See [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812) for examples.

Comment: Easiest to do this with `biblatex`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373336/2693 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537992/2693

Comment: If you use author-year citations in your text, there is little point in adding numbers in the bibliography. In fact those numbers can take away focus from what is important to find the relevant item in the bibliography (namely name and year). That's why the default settings don't let you combine author-year citations and a numeric bibliography like this. Do you really, absolutely need this?

Comment: If that is the case, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537992/35864. The first part of the answer was written with `apacite` in mind, but you get the structurally same result (and the result you want) if you replace `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` with just `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`/`\bibliographystyle{apalike2}`.

Comment: Are you sure? I just verified that the code works as intended in the following MWE: https://gist.github.com/moewew/1b38e4f32990da5f99d0c88d7ba23250. You need to use `\numbibliography{<bib file name>}` and not `\bibliography{<bib file name>}`.

Comment: That's what I see after the first pdfLaTeX run. If I run BibTeX and then pdfLaTeX twice more I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkznm.png. Do you get any warnings or errors in the `.log` or `.blg` files?

Comment: What does the `.blg` file say when you run BibTeX?

Comment: This is what it says: `Process started: bibtex.exe "texstudio_QiTrwL"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
The top-level auxiliary file: texstudio_QiTrwL.aux
The style file: apalike2.bst
I couldn't open database file apa5ex.bib
---line 6 of file texstudio_QiTrwL.aux
 : \bibdata{apa5ex
 :                }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file texstudio_QiTrwL.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "apa6:ch7-ex38"
(There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: Alright, but that message is just because your system does not have the example `.bib` file used in the code (which is weird, but could be explained if you did not install a full system). I have updated the example at https://gist.github.com/moewew/1b38e4f32990da5f99d0c88d7ba23250 to come with its own example `.bib` entry. Can you get it to work now?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked well though the number labels are not aligned to the left margin.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537992/35864 `apalike2` does not provide information about the longest label, so the label width is hard-coded (to 1em in the example with `\setlength{\labelwidth}{1em}%`), this might not be the best value if your have many entries, so you may have to experiment with the value.

Comment: Noted with many thanks @moewe