# Which bibliography stile to have the references with "et al." after the third author and the (year) after the authors?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am working on a LaTeX chapter for a Springer book for the [Methods in Molecular Biology (MIMB)](https://www.springer.com/series/7651) series. This is my header:

`\documentclass[graybox,vecphys]{svmult}`

For the bibliography, I am using the `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}` command and my references have the following format:

> Abadi, M., Barham, P., Chen, J., Chen, Z., Davis, A., Dean, J., Devin,
>   M., Ghemawat, S., Irving, G., Isard, M., Kudlur, M., Levenberg, J.,
>   Monga, R., Moore, S., Murray, D.G., Steiner,B., Tucker, P., Vasudevan,
>   V., Warden, P., Wicke, M., Yu, Y., Zheng, X.: TensorFlow: a system for
>   large-scale machine learning. In: Proceedings of OSDI 2016 – the 12th
>   USENIX Symposium on Operating Systems Design and Implementation, pp.
>   265–283 (2016).

But this is not the style requested by Springer MIMB. I need to find a style that puts the **year after the names**, puts **"et al." after the third author**, removes all the dots after the abbreviated first names, removes "In" and "and".
That is, it should print the above example as:

> Abadi M, Barham P, Chen J. et al. (2016) TensorFlow: a system for
>   large-scale machine learning. Proceedings of OSDI 2016 – the 12th
>   USENIX Symposium on Operating Systems Design and Implementation:
>   265–283.

Please notice the "et al." and the position of the (2016) year.

Which style can I use to achieve this result?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: I found a way to insert "et al." after the 3rd co-author, to keep the reference list numeric, to remove the "In:" and the "and". The steps are the following.

At the top of my LaTeX file, I had to insert:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, maxnames=3, minnames=3, firstinits=true, sorting=none, terseinits=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{bibliography_file.bib}
```

At the bottom of my LaTeX file, I had to remove:

```
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{bibliography_file}
```

and I had to insert:

```
\printbibliography
```

These commands led to the following result:

> Abadi M, Barham P, Chen J, et al. “TensorFlow: a system for large-scale
>   machine learning”. Proceedings of OSDI 2016 – the 12th USENIX Symposium on 
>   Operating Systems Design and Implementation. 2016, pp. 265–283.

I still need to solve an issues: I have to move the (year) to have it after the name list. **How can I get that?** Thanks!

Comment: Your bibliography-related formatting needs, and especially the name truncation requirements, are sufficiently special to make it unlikely that they can be satisfied with an existing bibliography style. I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is a part of the `custom-bib` package. Open a command window and type `latex makebst` to start an interactive session; you'll get lots of questions, each with an array of possible answers (one of which is marked as the default). At the end of process, you'll get a bespoke bib style file that will do what you need.

Comment: Something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314071/87678

Comment: Is your question solved with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314071/87678? After the edit, it is pretty much a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Any news here? Is your question solved with the linked question or do you need more?

Answer (score 1):

I read some posts online and I came to this solution. I added these commands and the top of my LaTeX main file:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=none,
    maxnames=3, minnames=3, firstinits=true, terseinits=true,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}    

\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother    

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\addbibresource{bibliography_file.bib}
```

And this is the result:

> Abadi M, Barham P, Chen J, et al. (2016). TensorFlow: a system for
>   large-scale machine learning. Proceedings of OSDI 2016 – the 12th
>   USENIX Symposium on Operating Systems Design and Implementation,
>   265–283.

Thank to everyone who helped!

Comment: What is numeric.bbx?