# IEEE style giving error in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran

I've been have a really hard time getting the IEEE style for `biblatex` to work.  If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

I've installed the publishing packages suggest [here](http://softwareexperiments.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/installing-ieeetrans-and-the-ieee-bibtex-style-for-latex-in-ubuntu/).  I get the error:

```
!Package biblatex Error: Style 'IEEEtran` not found
```

Here is what my `.tex` file looks like

```
\usepackage[stye=IEEEtran}{biblatex}
...
\bibliography{reference.bib}
```

and

```
\usepackage{stye=IEEEtran}{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
....
\printbibliography
```

I have also tried `style=ieee`, `style=ieeetr`, etc. Any help would be appreciated.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 if that helps.

Comment: Are you writing for submission to the IEEE? If you are, I can't recommend using `biblatex` and the `ieee` style as this is 'unofficial'.

Comment: are you really writing `\usepackage{stye=IEEEtran}{biblatex}`?  the first argument is surely optional, so `\usepackage[stye=IEEEtran]{biblatex}` (or whatever); however, i would pay attention to joseph's warning

Comment: The site you are linking to points only to the ieeetran package. This package contains only bibtex support files. For biblatex you will have to install the `biblatex-ieee` package. After the installation you can use it with `\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}` or with `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`.

Comment: @Joseph I have to use IEEE (computer engineer) for my reports.

Comment: @Ulrike should I use biblatex or bibtex? What is the difference?

Comment: biblatex + biber + a biblatex style like biblatex-ieee is modern, flexible and powerful. But as Joseph said it is not an official way. If you only need the bibliography to *look* like IEEE you can try it. If you want to submit your `tex`-file e.g. to a journal you should ask them first.

Comment: Thank you for the comments it really helped me out.  

I switched the backend to use biber and manually grabbed the biblatex-ieee styles. An important note is that Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have biber in its repositories so you have to install it manually.  Also you need to use the most recent version of biblatex (2.6 as of writing this).  This [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61370/configuring-a-biblatex-bibliography-style) really helped me out also in understanding how to set up everything.

Comment: This question is most definitely NOT too localised. Need to do this!

Comment: Use `\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}`. It worked for me